# Hibernate session get method returns proxy object

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy

I am confused with the Hibernate session `get` method. My understanding is that the `get` method always returns real object and not the proxy object ([ref](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/)).

But in my program I get the proxy object even when I use the `get` method.

My scenario:

I have two tables `product` and `company`.

Product JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "prd_id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "price")
   private int price;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "cmp_id")
   private Company company;
}
```

Company JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
public class Company {


  @Id
  @Column(name = "cmp_id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "address")
  private String address;

  @Column(name = "revenue")
  private int revenue;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
  private List<Product> products;
}
```

In my main method I have the following code:

```
    Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, 1); // this product has cmp_id 1
    System.out.println("Got product");
    Company company = (Company) session.get(Company.class, 1);
    System.out.println(company instanceof HibernateProxy); // this returns true
```

I know because of the lazy loading Hibernate has company 1 as proxy object from `Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, 1);`.
But I was expecting `(Company) session.get(Company.class, 1);` to return normal object.

From the log, I see hibernate does hit the database and get complete data of Company object. This makes it more confusing, if hibernate has all the data why is still returning the proxy object ?

Is my understanding incorrect ? How can ensure session `get` returns normal object and not a proxy object ?

Comment: One of the commentators (Lluis) of the reference you gave states: "Javadoc says: Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, or null if there is no such persistent instance. (If the instance is already associated with the session, return that instance. This method never returns an uninitialized instance.)

It will hit the database just once. Subsequent calls with the same id will return the cached instance."

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not hit the database for every call to `get`.

See JavaDocs for get:[If the instance is already associated with the session, return that instance. This method never returns an uninitialized instance.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable))

So, since with `session.get(Product.class)` there's already an instance of Company in the session (although a proxy) so Hibernate just initializes that proxy (thus the sql you saw).

Comment: Could you explain what do mean by initializes the proxy ? The `Company company = (Company) session.get(Company.class, 1);` statement causes the select query execution (`select .. from company`). And ever after executing the select query, the proxy object properties are uninitialized.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the FetchType.LAZY on your association. So you're saying after the get(Company.class,1) i.e. company.name is uninitialized (null)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all **session.get never returns a proxy object** it returns a fully initialized object from the persistent space if it is present there otherwise it hits the database to get the object from there and give it back else returns null.

As the java doc says :

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, or null if there is no such persistent instance. (If the instance is already associated with the session, return that instance. This method never returns an uninitialized instance.)

For more information you can follow the link "http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class, java.io.Serializable)" .